# Вёрстка пагинации на гридах

Tags: css, вёрстка, pagination, css-grid, пагинация

Здравствуйте, подскажите каким образом можно дополнить стили, чтобы пагинация не ломалась при уменьшении ширины экрана?

Сейчас выходит следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а хотелось бы добиться такого результата:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй пример я получил при добавлении `min-width: min-content;` к классу `.pagination__item`

но на более широком экране последний элемент не хочет переходить на новую строку и получается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.pagination {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: start;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(32px, 1fr));
}

.pagination__list {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(32px, min-content));
}

.pagination__item {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #444444;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-top-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-right-color: #c4c4c4;
  border-bottom-color: #c4c4c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <div class="pagination__list">
    <div class="pagination__item">1</div>
    <div class="pagination__item">2</div>
    <div class="pagination__item">3</div>
    <div class="pagination__item">4</div>
    <div class="pagination__item">5</div>
    <div class="pagination__item">6</div>
    <div class="pagination__item">7</div>
    <div class="pagination__item">8</div>
    <div class="pagination__item">9</div>
    <div class="pagination__item">10</div>
    <div class="pagination__item">11</div>
    <div class="pagination__item">12345678</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо использовать **Flex box**. Grid для такой цели не подходит, так как предполагает равный размер ячеек в колонке.

```css
.pagination {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.pagination div {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #444444;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-top-color: #dbdbdb;
  border-right-color: #c4c4c4;
  border-bottom-color: #c4c4c4;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>111111</div>
  <div>222222222</div>
  <div>333333333333</div>
  <div>44444444444444</div>
</div>
```

Comment: весь проект на гридах, хотелось бы дальше их использовать, но если нет вариантов воспользуюсь вашим примером, спасибо!